# Is InMemoryUploadedFile really "in memory"?

Tags: python, django, memory-management

I understand that opening a file just creates a file handler that takes a fixed memory irrespective of the size of the file.
Django has a type called `InMemoryUploadedFile` that represents files uploaded via forms.

I get the handle to my file object inside the django view like this:

```
file_object = request.FILES["uploadedfile"]
```

This file_object has type `InMemoryUploadedFile`.

Now we can see for ourselves that, file_object has the method `.read()` which is used to read files into memory.

```
bytes = file_object.read()
```

Wasn't **file_object** of type `InMemoryUploadedFile` already "in memory"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `read()` method on a file object is way to access content from within a file object irrespective of whether that file is in memory or stored on the disk. It is similar to other utility file access methods like `readlines` or `seek`.

The behavior is similar to what is [built into](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) Python which in turn is built over the operating system's `fread()` method.

> Read at most size bytes from the file (less if the read hits EOF
>   before obtaining size bytes). If the size argument is negative or
>   omitted, read all data until EOF is reached. The bytes are returned as
>   a string object. An empty string is returned when EOF is encountered
>   immediately. (For certain files, like ttys, it makes sense to continue
>   reading after an EOF is hit.) Note that this method may call the
>   underlying C function fread() more than once in an effort to acquire
>   as close to size bytes as possible. Also note that when in
>   non-blocking mode, less data than was requested may be returned, even
>   if no size parameter was given.

On the question of where exactly the `InMemoryUploadedFile` is stored, it is a [bit more complicated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/).

> Before you save uploaded files, the data needs to be stored somewhere.
>
> By default, if an uploaded file is smaller than 2.5 megabytes, Django
>   will hold the entire contents of the upload in memory. This means that
>   saving the file involves only a read from memory and a write to disk
>   and thus is very fast.
>
> However, if an uploaded file is too large, Django will write the
>   uploaded file to a temporary file stored in your system’s temporary
>   directory. On a Unix-like platform this means you can expect Django to
>   generate a file called something like /tmp/tmpzfp6I6.upload. If an
>   upload is large enough, you can watch this file grow in size as Django
>   streams the data onto disk.
>
> These specifics – 2.5 megabytes; /tmp; etc. – are simply “reasonable
>   defaults”. Read on for details on how you can customize or completely
>   replace upload behavior.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but doesn't answer my question exactly. Is `InMemoryUploadedFile` necessarily in memory or is it stored on the disk?

Comment: Have updated my answer for that.  < 2.5 Mb is actually InMemory and otherwise it is a temp file on disk. The defaults can be changed in settings and have their limitations.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to consider is that in python file like objects have an API that is pretty strictly adhered to.  This allows code to be very flexible, they are abstractions over I/O streams.  These allow your code to not have to worry about where the data is coming from, ie. memory, filesystem, network, etc.

[File like](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#i-o-base-classes) objects usually define a couple [methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#i-o-base-classes), one of which is `read`

I am not sure of the actually implementation of `InMemoryUploadedFile`, or how they are generated or where they are stored (I am assuming they are totally in memory though), but you can rest assured that they are file like objects and contain a `read` method, because they adhere to the file api.

For the implementation you could start checking out the source:

- https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py#L90
- https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/base.py
- https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/uploadhandler.py

Comment: [IOBase](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase) can be considered a file-like object interface (or [TextIOBase](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase)).

Comment: Ok, I understand now that `InMemoryUploadedFile` is a file like object, but is it stored in the memory or on the disk?  This question is of importance, since it limits the size of the user uploads a server of small RAM can handle.